# Can you use a stored proc in a cfoutput like you can a query?

Tags: stored-procedures, coldfusion

I know you can define a `<cfquery>...</cfquery>` and then do something like:

```
<cfoutput query="QueryName">
    <option value = "#data#">#data2#, #data3#</option>
</cfoutput>
```

However, if you define a `<cfstoredproc>...</cfstoredproc>`, assign it a name, can you then just plug in that name in the `query` attribute and get the same result?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: I cannot try it at this moment. I don't have the permissions to create stored procs where I work and need to wait on someone else. I'd rather not wait if I can get a simple answer somewhere.

Comment: As long as your storedproc returns a resultset it should work fine.

Comment: You can use `<cfoutput query=...">` with anything that returns a named query. A Stored Proc (with `<cfresultset...>`), `<cfdirectory action="list" ...>`, etc.

Comment: _"I don't have the permissions to create stored procs where I work"_ - this is just one of many reasons why you should have your own local copy of the databases you're working with.

Comment: @PeterBoughton, not everyone is in your situation.

Comment: Um, I don't have a "situation". Shared development servers are simply a flawed concept.

Comment: [RTM](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfstoredproc)

Comment: I second Duncan's suggestion. There should be no need to ask a question like this, as the answer is CLEARLY in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the `cfprocresult` tag with your query name and then you can use it the same way that you do for a query.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d55.html

```
<cfstoredproc procedure = "foo_proc" dataSource = "MY_SYBASE_TEST" > 
    <cfprocresult name = "yourQueryName"> 
</cfstoredproc> 

<cfoutput query="yourQueryName">
<option value = "#data#">#data2#, #data3#</option>
</cfoutput>
```